# Multiple models in a single tastypie resource

Tags: django, tastypie

I'd like to make a single tastypie resource that returns the common fields from two different models.

I have models described as so:

```
Class Invoice(models.Model):
    transaction_batch = models.ForeignKey(TransactionBatch)
    invoice_number = models.IntegerField()
    subtotal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Delivery_location)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()

Class Payment(models.Model):
    transaction_batch = models.ForeignKey(TransactionBatch)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Delivery_location)
    payment_id = models.IntegerField(pk=True)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    payment_method = models.IntegerField(choices = PAYMENT_METHOD_CHOICES)
```

And would like to make a resource with the following fields:

```
Class TransactionResource(Resource):
    type = fields.CharField() #"invoice" or "payment"
    id = fields.CharField(attribute='name') #invoice_number or payment_id
    location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource)
    total = fields.IntegerField(attribute='total', null=True) #total or amount
    datetime = fields.DateField()
```

As the field names don't match up directly, I will need a way to map the Model field to the Resource field.  For example,  the resource ID field will be invoice_number for Invoices and payment_id for Payments.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to inherit from ModelResource, you can add additional values using the dehydrate method:

```
class TransactionResource(Resource):
    type = fields.CharField() #"invoice" or "payment"
    id = fields.CharField(attribute='name') #invoice_number or payment_id
    location = fields.ForeignKey(LocationResource)
    total = fields.IntegerField(attribute='total', null=True) #total or amount
    datetime = fields.DateField()

    # Add values in dehydrate
    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['some_invoide_value'] = invoice.value
        bundle.data['some_payment_value'] = payment.value
        return super(TransactionResource, self).dehydrate(bundle)
```